# Tug something vs. tug at something?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, verbs

If **tug** gives meaning of "drew or pull something"

So why we would add **prep** to it. then would act as intransitive verb? At the time it gives meaning that it doesn't need a preposition.

> - she tugged at her sleeve to get her attention

Could we use the verb with no preposition, and still gives the same meaning? , or in another words, why do we need prep after the verb?

Answer (score 2):

If you *tug* something, you pull on it and it moves.  You might tug a rope three times to give someone a signal.

If you *tug at* something, you pull on it and *nothing happen*.  You tug at someone's sleeve, the sleeve doesn't go anywhere.